# Dissolve a intersection along id and keep only features of the bigger area QGIS

Tags: qgis, area, dissolve

In QGIS I'm trying to dissolve an intersection and keep only the features with the bigger area [blue arrow] (compared with other features with same id [red box]). I'm interested in keeping other information (in my example picture marked in yellow)

[image: Example of the table]

The intersection resolutes from a buffer of a polyline (coastline) with 1 km segments and a polygon. I want to transfer information from the polygon to the coastline for each segment of the polyline. But I want to transfer the information of the polygon sharing the biggest intersected area with the buffer.

Would be amazing if there is a way to do this using the graphical modeller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Virtual Layer:

(Change *islands* to the name of your layer)

```
select islands.*
from islands
inner join
    (select id, max(area) as maxarea from islands group by id) as maxarea
on islands.id = maxarea.id
and islands.area=maxarea.maxarea
```

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-partition-by-another-column-in-mys

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for replying. Just by replacing islands by the name of my layer i get a invalid layer.